# Unable to show psensor readings in system tray Arch, Gnome 3.38

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3

I have currently arch linux installed with Gnome 3.38.3. With Psensors, I am unable to show the temperature in the system tray. In the settings of psensor, there is application indicator, from where we can choose what to show in the system tray. But that section is greyed out for me. Hence I am unable to choose it.

Are there any dependencies that I might be missing.

I have installed psensor, lm_sensor, hddtemp, sensors-applet pacakges. Are there any more packages to install.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to show the Psensor readings. But I was able to find a substitute for it. It is a gnome shell extension called [Vitals](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/). Over there numerous statistics can be displayed in the system tray.

I personally use temperature, ram usage, CPU usage.